# Mount storage from host in bhyve VM

Tags: mount, freebsd, virtual-machine

Is it possible to mount storage space from the host environment inside a bhyve virtual machine? I could use a network share, but I figure there would be less overhead mounting the data directly. I'm looking for something like Virtual Box's "shared storage".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There's been some work being done on VirtFS (aka virtio-9p) in bhyve, see this [Mailing list thread](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2016-February/049068.html). This is somewhat experimental and at the moment it seems only Linux guests are supported. The code [can be found in a github repository](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/compare/master...jceel:virtfs).

On the other hand, bhyve's [virtio-net performance is pretty good](http://empt1e.blogspot.de/2016/11/bhyve-vs-virtualbox-benchmarking-part2.html) and the overhead of nfs is pretty negligible. In constrast to virtio-9p, nfs is well tested and stable.